# Wamp Server not working in Windows

Tags: localhost, wamp, wampserver

My wamp server works good even with Skype also because i remove this "use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections" tick in Skype tool menu. but once my pc restart because of light problem now it stop working.

- Wamp symbol is show in orange color.
- It show **localhost** but when i open **phpmyadmin** then show error.
  ( #2002 - The server is not responding )
- Click on Wamp Symbol and in MySql -> Service -> Stop Service and Restart Service both shows Disable, and I click on Start/Resume Service don't effect.

  - I check that on port 80 not any other program working.
  - I close all other background program like Skype
  - I reinstall and restart Wamp Server and my PC.
  - I restart all services many times.
  - firewall is also turns to off.

So will anybody says that whats problem in wamp in my pc. I stuck from 2 days and search on internet lots but can't get solution.

Thanks...

Comment: Have you checked apache error log?

Comment: Yes but i didn't find find any problem there. or i didn't understand what's problem.

Comment: Do you mean that you are able to visit localhost, but not MySQL?

Comment: yes exactly. when i open MySQL the error shown above given.

Comment: Have you checked MySQL logs. Try deleting all the MySQL data and reinstalling WAMP .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Wampmanager icon in the system tray is Orange then one of the services has not started.

Obviously MySQL in this case.

Look at your `MySQL error log` and `Windows Event Viewer`, for `error messages from MySQL`, that should tell you what the problem is.

If you tried installing Apache and MySQL independantly before you installed WAMPServer make sure they are both properly uninstalled. Also check there is no `my.ini` file anywhere on your system except inside the C:\wamp folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

I will Solve the problem. First i take backup of www folder and uninstall Wamp Server and then after remove wamp folder manually. then install again wamp. it works now perfect.

Thanks for help all